# Change aspect ratio of pictures

Tags: camera, photos, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

How can I simply change the aspect ratio of pictures on Android 4.2.2? Say from 1920x1080 to 1920x1280.

Background: On my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini, I can take pictures using the native camera app and this gives normal results. I have a remote that needs its special camera app ("Snap remote"), and the output of this app comes in the wrong aspect ratio.

I wrote the developers but they haven't replied or fixed it.

Comment: Converting a 1080p image to 1920x1080 would involve cropping to 1620x1080 and then scaling it up to maintain the aspect ratio.  Changing or fixing the aspect ratio would mean just vertical scaling.  Which are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to crop the picture. I want something like in Photoshop, "Image > Image Size" and then you change from 1920x1080 to 1920x1280. I am not sure if Photoshop is interpolating something there...

Comment: Yeah, Photoshop has several interpolation options.  Photoshop Express does not seem to have an option to scale up.  I tried a few other photo editors, and only one seemed to have an option to scale up but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This guy works great for me on a Samsung 8.4" pro tab:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.valsior.resizer

Has a long list of pre-set sizes and a select-your-own-size option, which like photoshop allows you to choose whether you want to maintain the aspect ratio or not.  You can choose file type and quality as well when saving.

Comment: Very nice, worked for me as well.

Comment: Works fine for me. Does anybody know how to set the language for this app to avoid the horrible translation?